# Conditional Inner jopin logic

Tags: ms-access-2010, case, inner-join

I currently have a table as (Sample snapshot):

```
Table1
Employee ID Old Value      New Value         Update Date
1           Analyst        non-employee     10/1/2012
1           non-employee   Senior Analyst   10/1/2012
2           Analyst        non-employee      9/1/2012
2           non-employee   Assistant Mgr.    9/1/2012
2           Assistant Mgr. non-employee     10/1/2015
2           non-employee   Manager          10/1/2015
3           Analyst        non-employee     10/1/2015
3           non-member     Manager          10/1/2015
4           Analyst        non-employee      9/1/2012
4           non-employee   Senior Analyst    9/1/2012
4           Senior Analyst non-employee     10/1/2015
4           non-employee   Assistant Mgr.   10/1/2015
4           Assistant Mgr. non-employee     10/6/2015
4           non-employee   Manager          10/6/2015
```

From this table, I need to pick out those employee IDs that transitioned from analyst to manager directly,i.e. without becoming a assistant manager or senior analyst.

Desired Result:

```
Employee ID Old Value   New Value   Update Date
3           Analyst     Manager     10/1/2015
```

---

I have been trying to figure out a logic to use conditional inner join to get the desired result.. But I have had no luck so far. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How do you distinguish the ordering of values where the dates are the same?

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the response and I apologize for the date issue. I corrected the snapshot data. Whenever a person's title changes, it goes to non-employee first and then to the new title. I hope this clarifies your doubt and apology again for the incorrect data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then this query might work:

```
select t.id, t.oldvalue, tnext.newvalue, t.updatedate
from table t join
     table tnext
     on t.employeeid = tnext.employeeid and
        t.updatedate = tnext.updatedate and
        t.newvalue = 'non-employee' and
        tnext.oldvalue = 'non-employee'
where t.oldvalue = 'Analyst' and tnext.newvalue = 'Manager';
```

It should work on your sample data but (4) is troublesome because there are four changes on the same date.

Comment: Hi Gordon,
I am using access to run the query.Hence I am using INNER JOIN syntax to run the query. I get the error as JOIN Expression not supported for the part t.[New Value] = 'Non-Employee'. I was reading through other similar questions and was wondering if I should use Union function?

Comment: @HimanshuAgrawal . . . Your question is tagged MySQL.  If you want an answer with a different database, you should tag the question correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Gordon. Will keep that in mind for future.